# To reset DesiredCapabilities for a particular test case

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd, appium

Am using Appium+Java+Cucumber to develop test cases in a BDD environment for automating IOS App. The app we are automating has alert pop-ups which shows up when we run tests on a particular feature. To handle this I set
capabilities.setCapability("autoDismissAlerts", true);

But now I need this capability to be set to False for one of the test case.

How to achieve this?

I tried several ways to find a solution but I am not successful.

One of the ways, I explored was to tag that particular test case for which I did not want to dismiss the Alert pop-up. This tag was additional to the tag what we already use to identify the test case.

Something like

@x @DontDismissAlert

And then in the Before hook, I got the 2 tags of this particular test case by using getSourceTagNames(). But am unable to expose these tags outside Before hook class. Because of this am unable to create a condition to set capabilities for autoDismissAlerts based on the tags.

Someone please help me how to expose these tags to be consumed by other classes.

Also I want to know is there any other way I can set capability for autoDismissAlerts to False based on some condition.

Comment: An example would be nice. Are you able to share some code that describes your issue?